# Fuse not being enabled in gentoo

Tags: kernel, kernel-modules, gentoo, fuse

I'm on Gentoo 201512 (KDE).

I installed Fuse, but running the fuse example "passthrough" program as `./passthrough /mnt/test` gives me a message `fuse: device not found, try 'modprobe fuse' first`.

So I ran `modprobe fuse` which then say `FATAL: Module fuse not found`.

So I figured I need to install fuse, so I did `emerge --ask sys-fs/fuse` but still the same issue.

With some more googling, I went to `/usr/src/linux` and ran `make menuconfig` and enabled the `File system -> Fuse ....` option.

Then ran `make module module-install`.

Then ran `modprobe fuse` which returns nothing back. Running `./passthrough /mnt/test` gives me the same error: `fuse: device not found, try 'modprobe fuse' first`.

Running `lsmod` does not show fuse.

I tried `modprobe -r fuse` just in case, and it strangely gives `modprobe: FATAL: Module fuse is builtin`. What does that even mean?? If it's built-in shouldn't I be able to use it?

(I also enabled `Enable loadable module support -> Forced module loading` because that seemed like what I would need after I did all the above. Same result)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what happened.

Turns out the file `make menuconfig` edits is different from `/usr/src/linux/.config`

I editted `usr/src/linux/.config` so that it has `CONFIG_FUSE_FS=m`